# Is there anyway in CSS to make the page width variable?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a page that has no vertical scroll, rather, everything is displayed horizontally.

if you scroll all the way to the end of my page (all the way to the right) you will see my contact info.
For example:

```
<div1></div1>
<div2></div2>
<div3></div3>
<divN></divN>
```

In this case, div1 is the most left item, with div2 in the center div3 to the right of it... and all the way at the end, divN is displayed. 
every div is 500 px wide. 
I can set my page width to 20000px ( for 4 divs ) and that works great. 
However, I wanna make my page dynamic and each div, other than divN is loaded from a database. This means, each time I add content, I have to manually increase my page width.

Is there a way to automate this process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per i understand may be that's you want this:

```
.parent{
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
}

.parent > div{
    width:500px;
    height:300px;
    border:1px solid red;
    display:inline-block;
    *display:inline;/*For IE7*/
    *zoom:1;
    white-space:normal;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/HJsrJ/

Comment: Or perhaps `overflow-x:scroll;`.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use `width:100%` for an external div and make other divs `width:33%` with every content floated in the right way?

[See example](http://jsfiddle.net/9m5Fd/)

Answer (score 0):

You could save the CSS into a table, inserting placeholders where you want to dynamically change values. Heck, this could even just be a template file somewhere. Then, whenever you publish a new section on the base, pull the template, string-replace the placeholders, and then write the new CSS out to file.

Make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to give each of these div a class then use javasript to count the number of classes present multiply this by the required width of each div then use javascript to set the page width with the on document ready event.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what OP wants here, but here's a 'solution':

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div id="div1">1 has content</div>
    <div id="div2" class="nocontent"><!-- no content --></div>
    <div id="div3">3 has content</div>
    <div id="div4">4 has content</div>
    <div id="div5" class="nocontent"><!-- no content --></div>
    <div id="div6" class="nocontent"><!-- no content --></div>
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
.parent {
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.parent > div {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    margin-left: 1px;
    background: #eee;
}

.parent > .nocontent {
    display: none;            
}
​
```

JavaScript (jQuery):

```
$(function() {
   // Simulate loading content
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#div2').text('2 has content now').removeClass('nocontent');
    }, 3000);
});​
```

Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/foxbunny/EY9sc/